# Linked List quetion

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

In the below code snippet, the count function counts the number of nodes in created linked list. I wonder how does the next address gets passed from `count(C_list->next);` function call?

```
struct linked_list
{
 int number;
 struct linked_list *next;
};
typedef struct linked_list node;

main()
{
    head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    create(head);
    print(head);
    c = count(head);
}
int count(node* C_list)
{
    if(C_list->next==NULL)
      return(0);
    else
    {
      return(1+count(C_list->next));//How does the next address gets passed from this function call?
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how this(the recursion) is working?  Your code already sends the next address. What is the output of your program?

Comment: Note that this is an incredibly ineffective, obfuscated way of counting the nodes of a linked list. Professional code would not use recursion but a plain loop. Recursion is almost always an incredibly bad way to solve practical programming problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
main()
{
    head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    create(head);
    print(head);
    c = count(head);         //See here you are sending the actual node, which is head.
}
int count(node* C_list)
{
    if(C_list->next==NULL)   //-->Here the if condition is checking for the next node (head->next) whether it is null or not.
      return(0);            //-->If the next node is null, it means no nodes are there. So returning 0.
    else
    {
      return(1+count(C_list->next));
    }
}
```

Now the tricky part is the return line, in which you are passing `C_list->next` i.e., `head->next` to the count function. And now after recursion, in the above `if` condition it checks for the next node address i.e., `head->next->next` and it goes on until the node is `null`, this way the next address is getting passed for the recursive function. Hope this might have helped you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clarification!

Answer (score 0):

First, I must suggest you read a book on C as it seems your question is "the obvious". So here is a part from my book:

The expression `C_list->next` in the function call is evaluated and the result is passed as the argument to the function.

The expression takes the `C_list` variable (a pointer), dereferences it and then takes the `next` member. This value of `next`, which points to the next node of the list, is then passed as the argument to the function.

The function now continues with this next node.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clarification!